# Issue with getting a single row in zf2 pdo

Tags: pdo, zend-framework2

I am trying to fetch the single row using the pdo statement, but i am getting the error like ..

Fatal error: call to undefined method fetch()

```
$sql = new Sql( $this->adapter );
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from('users');
    $where = new  Where();
    $where->equalTo('user_id',$userId);
    $select->where($where);

    //echo $select->getSqlString($this->adapter->getPlatform());

    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

    $result = $statement->execute();


    $row = $statement->fetch();

    //getting the result set for the below, but not the above statement fetch
    $rows = array_values(iterator_to_array($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "fetch" method  in the statement object. If you want to get a single row then get the current entry of the result iterator, like so:

```
$row = $result->current();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php, here i can find the methods isnt it.. note the line..PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set

Comment: Ok, I got your point here. Let me make it clear. The method $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select); does NOT return an instance of PDOStatement instead it returns an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement. However, you can get PDOStatement from the Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement object via getResource method